# What is the difference between "*#id" and "#id" jquery selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Serendipitously I've come across an interesting situation. Someone changed this:

```
var x = $('#someId');
```

To this:

```
var x = $('*#someId');
```

The asterisk was literally the only change and the author of the commit says this fixes some problem (I don't know what, I can't contact them and it's not really relevant to me). I'm stumped - to my best understanding that asterisk should not change anything. The selectors are for all practical purposes identical. What don't I know? In what situation would the output from the two commands be different?

Comment: "In what situation would the output from the two commands be different?" — Aside from the addition of the `*` having a likely negative (although unlikely a significant one) there shouldn't be any circumstance where it makes a difference.

Comment: Are there multiple elements with the same id in your HTML? `$("#id")` will select only the first, whereas the `*` will select all elements with the given id (note that having multiple elements with the same id is invalid HTML)

Comment: @NickParsons - Possibly, I don't know and can't find out.

Comment: That's at least one difference, the first only selects the first element with the given id, the second selects all elements with the given id. If you can execute the code then you can use `.length` on both to see how many elements match, if it's different for both then that implies multiple elements with the same id

Comment: If you open your browser developer tools you can execute `$('*#someId');` in the console  and compare the output to that of `$('#someId');`. If it doesn't make a difference then maybe they weren't fixing what they though they were fixing.

Comment: @PeterKrebs [There is no difference](https://jsfiddle.net/v62qr405/1/). Well...unless [there is](https://jsfiddle.net/qde67w2t/). It's not as trivial to check as you describe here.

Comment: *says this fixes some problem* - it fixes your previous dev's inability to use unique IDs.  It's not a good solution and the underlying problem should be fixed as it will continue to be an issue, and a hard to find one at that.